# DVC error : scmrepo.exceptions.SCMError: Empty git repo

Tags: python-3.x, git, pipeline, dvc

I tried initializing DVC and was getting this error .
I am not using GIT actively to track anything although git is initialised . I am trying to create some plots

```
from dvclive import Live
live = Live("evaluation2/metrics")
```

[image]

does anyone have any idea on this . I am new to DVC so might be very silly issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue / limitation that is being worked on at the moment:

- [Show a setup screen when project has no commits](https://github.com/iterative/vscode-dvc/pull/3253)
- [`exp init`/`exp run`: fails if the repo has no root commit](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/8839)
- [`exp`: improve ui for empty Git repos](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/7548)

The simplest workaround is to create at least a single commit in the repository before running it.